# Next lexicographic permutation of a list

Tags: beginner, haskell

I began learning Haskell last week.  I wrote the following to get the next lexicographic permutation of a list.  It works perfectly but I feel like I'm just writing a c# method.  My long list of where commands just feels like an imperative approach.  I would appreciate any feedback if this solution is indeed the way most people would write something like this in haskell:

```
-- Finds the end of a list that is monotonically decreasing (swap)
-- Pivot is the index just before it. (pivot)
-- exchanges the smallest value > pivot in swap with pivot
-- reverses the swap with the pivot in it, and concatenates the new permutation
nextPerm :: (Ord a,Num a) => [a] -> [a]
nextPerm [] = []
nextPerm a = if pivotIndex == (-1) then a 
             else prePivot ++ [swapVal] ++ swapWithPivot
             where
                 swap = foldl (\acc x -> if x<=(last acc) then acc ++ [x] else [x]) [(-1)] a
                 pivotIndex = (length a) - (length swap) - 1
                 prePivot = take pivotIndex a
                 pivotVal = a !! pivotIndex
                 swapVal = foldl1 (\acc x -> if x > pivotVal then x else acc) swap
                 swapWithPivot = insert pivotVal $ delete swapVal $ reverse swap
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a beginner at Haskell as well, so take my opinion with a big rock of salt.

```
nextPerm :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> [a]
nextPerm [] = []
nextPerm a
```

I wouldn't use `a` as a type variable and a variable at the same time. 
I like to name lists `xs, ys, cs`, etc. I feel this is more descriptive, and it works well with pattern-matching, e.g. `(x:xs)`, where `x` is the head of the list, `xs` is the tail.

`swap = foldl (\acc x -> if x <= (last acc) then acc ++ [x] else [x]) [(-1)] a`

Here you are going through the list from the front. When you use `last`, the program has to go through the whole list, because lists are kind of like linked lists, think `[1,2,3] = 1 : 2 : 3 : []`, so accessing an element takes \$O(n) \$ time.
For the same reason, `(++)` is expensive, while `(:)` is cheap. Try running `swap` on a list of \$ 10^5 \$ size; it's slow.

Other than the speed factor, I think your implementation is OK!

If you want to make it faster, first of all you should change `swap`. For example, first reverse the list, then work on it - as lists are made to be accessed from the front, not the back. Let me show you an improved version of `swap` along with a few other changes.

```
nextPerm :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
nextPerm xs
  | null xs || pivotIndex == -1 = xs
  | otherwise = prePivot ++ swapVal : swapWithPivot
  where pivotIndex = length xs - length swap - 1
        prePivot = take pivotIndex xs
        pivotVal = xs !! pivotIndex
        swapVal = foldl1 (\acc x -> if x > pivotVal then x else acc) swap
        swapWithPivot = insert pivotVal . delete swapVal . reverse $ swap
        swap = reverse . fmap fst 
                       . takeWhile (uncurry (>=)) 
                       . (<*>) zip (\ls -> head ls:ls) 
                       . reverse $ xs
```

As you can see, this way, you don't even need to restrict yourself to the class `Num`.
To make it even better, figure out how to use `span` instead of `take`, and `takeWhile`. If you do that, you won't even need indexing anymore. 
  Use [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), play around in `ghci`, look at types using `:t <typename>` e.g. `:t span` - type signatures (and names) will usually tell you what a function does.

Lists are weak at random access, but kind of good at being sliced up; therefore I'd definitely drop the whole indexing thing.

Anyway, I will include how I'd write it, hopefully it'll give you some new ideas.

```
nextPerm' :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
nextPerm' = uncurry (++) . uncurry swap
                         . (fmap fst *** fmap fst)
                         . span (uncurry (>=))
                         . (<*>) zip (\ls -> head ls:ls)
                         . reverse
    where swap rpost [] = ([], rpost)
          swap rpost (pivot:rpre) = (reverse rpre, ins . span (<= pivot) $ rpost)
              where ins (le,[])   = le ++ [pivot]
                    ins (le,a:as) = a:le ++ pivot:as
```

If you want to test an implementation, issue

```
(sort . permutations $ [1,2,3,4,5]) == (take 120 $ iterate nextPerm [1,2,3,4,5])
```

If it works, the result will be `True`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  There is a lot of great information here and was able to learn a quite a bit , especially about currying.  Though I hate to say the code is bugged.  Even your example.  625431->631245.  Its because you only did half the pivot swap.. You stuck it in the post, but forgot to take its "swap" and stick it in the pre.  I was able to fix it and add a stop (your function just takes [3,2,1] back to [1,23]

Comment: @TonyChamberlain I shouldn't code or review code during the night. Sorry about that. Anyway, the codes now work, thanks for pointing out the errors.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much the amount of bindings in your `where` clause, but rather some other pitfalls. For example, `last acc` will traverse the whole accumulated list, which is rather inefficient. Also, `(++)` takes linear time. We can remove both from your `swap` by building the `acc` in reverse:

```
swap = foldl (\acc@(ac:_) x -> if x <= ac then x : acc else [x]) [negate 1] a
```

That brings us to naming. Lists are usually called `xs` (for `xs`es). That's just a minor nitpick, although it would make place for `a` as the first element of the accumulator.

Either way, the `Num` constraint should not be necessary. `(-1)` might even lead to a wrong `swap` if all other values are lesser, e.g.

```
nextPerm [(-5)..(-2)] -- your result will contain `-1`.
```

So instead, let us use `foldl1`:

```
swap = foldl1 (\acc@(ac:_) [x] -> if x <= ac then x : acc else [x]) (map return xs)
```

For the pivot value, you could use `splitAt` instead:

By the way, `swap == rest`, but now reversed, since the accumulator in `swap` is now reversed. Therefore, we need to reverse `swap` for `swapVal` or use `foldr1` here. However, `head . filter` covers your intend best, so I recommend that instead. We end up with

```
nextPerm :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
nextPerm [] = []
nextPerm xs = if pivotIndex == (-1) then xs
              else prePivot ++ [swapVal] ++ swapWithPivot
  where
    swap = foldl1 (\acc@(a:_) [x] -> if x <= a then x : acc else [x]) (map return xs)
    pivotIndex               = (length a) - (length swap) - 1
    (prePivot, pivotVal : _) = splitAt pivotIndex a
    swapVal                  = head . filter (> pivotVal) $ swap
    swapWithPivot            = insert pivotVal $ delete swapVal $ swap
```

However, all of this isn't very easy to read. It gets a *lot* easier if we reverse the list beforehand. But that's left for an exercise.